# Archlinux Broken after clearing of pacman orphans and cache

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, plasma

I get an error message when I log into plasma 'All shell packages are missing. This is an installation issue, please contact your distribution. '. And I can't open a konsole session anymore.
The last thing I did before, was performing a cleanup according to the arch wiki with

```
$ sudo pacman -Rns $(pacman -Qdttq)
$ sudo pacman -Sc
$ sudo find . -type l -! -exec test -e {} \; -print
```

then I realized that something was wrong.
I obviously broke something vital. Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

Comment: Are you sure those were the *exact and only* commands that you ran? Look in pacman's log; there is nothing there that should have broken your system...

Comment: Ok. Apparently `pacman -Qdttq` thought that konsole and plasma-nm were orphaned. I should really have looked through that list first...
How can I get konsole back? The problem is that I also cannot connect to the network atm, since I removed plasma-nm

Comment: I am able to access my root partition via chroot when I boot from an archlinux usb install drive, which I created according to
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media
Is there a way to reinstall konsole from there, without internet connection?
Note that, to make matters worse, I cleared my pacman cache after uninstalling konsole.

Comment: You don't need to install konsole; from the TTY just reinstall what you need, pacman doesn't need a GUI to work (nor does your network).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you also included a transcript of what is going wrong (i.e., what commands are breaking with exactly what error messages).  That said, you can usually fix things up by just reinstalling all the packages you might need.  So for example you could say:

```
pacman -Syu
pacman -S --needed base xorg-server xorg-server-utils plasma-meta
```

That should restore any packages you might have accidentally deleted.

If you can't even get a shell from which to run those commands, then switch to a different virtual terminal and log in in text mode.  By default systemd always keep a text login on VT6, which you can access by pressing Ctrl-Alt-F6.  (Ctrl-Alt-F1 will get you back from VT6 to the original console.)

Comment: thanks for the reply. The problem is, that I cannot open konsole, since apparently 'all shell packages are missing', according to plasma :(

Comment: Is there any other way to open a bash shell?

Comment: Yes, just log in from the console.  Press, say, Ctrl-Alt-F6 to switch to a text terminal and log in as root on the text terminal to run the pacman commands.

Comment: Your answer above, together with your comment solved my problem. I logged into the console with Ctrl-Alt-F6, connected to the internet via router + cable and dhcpdc, updated my system and reinstalled konsole and needed xorg and plasma packages. I know it should be common knowledge, but could you add Ctrl-Alt-F6 to your answer? I'll then mark it as the solution.